# ArchLinux Fails to Run Latest GitKraken (3.3.4)

Tags: libcurl, gitkraken

I'm trying to run 64 bit zipped GitKraken on an ArchLinux build machine (where I do not have super privileges), and the latest version of GitKraken (3.3.4) seems to have changed/broken something with lib curl.

With a previous release (3.1.1, 64 bit), I was able to run just by calling gitkraken. Then, at some point, I had to preload the correct (older) curl library like so to get GK to run:

> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3 ~/gitkraken/gitkraken.

With 3.3.4, it won't run with using the direct call to gitkraken:

> /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by
>   /home/kmiller/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node)),

If I do specify it, it seg faults:

> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3 ~/gitkraken/gitkraken Node started
>   time: 1519142744860 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

If I specify libcurl4, it wants version 3:

> LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4" ~/gitkraken/gitkraken Node started
>   time: 1519154390224 /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3'
>   not found (required by
>   /home/kmiller/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node)
>   Error: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: version`CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found
>   (required by
>   /home/kmiller/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node)
>       at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
>       at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:187:18)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/home/kmiller/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js:11:12)
>       at Object. (/home/kmiller/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js:1031:3)

Thank you in advance. GitKraken help sent me here :slightly_smiling_face:

**Solution:**
The preload library for 3.3.4 is gnutls, you can then run GitKraken like this:

> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.3 ~/gitkraken/gitkraken

Comment: This looks like application support, not a programming question.

Comment: Sorry, it did say "software tools commonly used by programmers" was one of the valid categories. If this was a noob move, sorry!